# OneSignal Swift Install file not found

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, onesignal

I'm trying to setup the OneSignal service for my Swift iOS app.
I've followed the SDK install instructions from OneSignals website: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

But I'm getting the following 2 errors

```
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/Kevin/Desktop/OneSignal-iOS-SDK-master 2/OneSignalSwiftExample/OneSignalSwiftExample/OneSignalSwiftExample-Bridging-Header.h'
```

and

```
'OneSignal/Onesignal.h' file not found.
```

Same issue with the unmodified OneSignalSwiftExample xCode project that they ship with the SDK.

I was wondering if anyone else has run into this issue and might have a solution?

Comment: Did you install it using Cocoapods and !use_frameworks in Podfile?

Comment: No, I actually went with the manual install without Cocaopods

Comment: So you ended up with .framework anyway. I think you should just remove the import from bridging header and try "import OneSignal" somewhere in your Swift code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved so you can either do a git pull or re-download the repo to reflect the changes.

Alternatively, to solve this problem locally:

1. Create a directory called **Headers** in iOS_SDK/Framework/OneSignal.Framework/Versions/A
2. Copy the **OneSignal.h** file (iOS_SDK/OneSignal/OneSignal.h) into this newly created directory.

Should be good to go.

Note: If you prefer dowing a manual import then you should clone / download the stable release [(v1.13.3)](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/releases) instead of the current repo.